# Can't detect my NTFS partition from Finder (Leopard)

Tags: mac, ntfs, mount, osx-leopard

From Leopard, I created a new NTFS partition for Windows using BootCamp.

Everything went fine : Windows 7 was installed correctly and its partition (C:) showed up in Leopard's Finder.

Then, from Windows 7, I created a new ntfs partition (D:) for my documents.
Windows 7 can see it, but in Leopard, the Finder and Disk Utility can't see it. they detect only the windows partition (C:).
How can I mount my Documents partition (D:) in Leopard?
Thank you for your help.

P.S.:
Here's the mapping of my disk:

Leopard (50gb) - Windows 7 (C: - ntfs - 40gb) - Documents (D: - ntfs - 60gb)

Answer (score 1):

This should let you see it:

http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/ (not free)

and not as good, but free

http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/

Comment: There is a FUSE for NTFS, as well: http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/

Comment: That dosen't explain why Leopard detect the windows partition, but not the other one.

Comment: Sure it does. I'm pretty sure Boot Camp uses some hokus pokus to allow access to the system drive of your Windows install. That doesn't mean you now get to see any NTFS volume connected to your system, mate.

Answer (score 1):

This may help.  [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) is a tool for booting linux on Intel Macs.  In the DMG is a utility called "Partition Inspector" that'll let you know if there are differences between the (EFI-style) GUID Partition Table and the (BIOS-style) Master Boot Record.

If you install it rEFIT, and hold down the option key at startup, a menu comes up to choose which OS you want to boot, and there is a utility you can access there that'll try to make the two boot records correspond.

My guess is that the second partition is known in the Master Boot Record, but not in the GUID Partition Table.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the D: partition during the Windows installation process or afterwards?  Can you live with a FAT32 partition (max file size 4GBs)?  That'll have native OSX read / write support.